# Why does this Grails Spock GroovyMock test fail (parameters are ignored)?

Tags: grails, mocking, spock

I have a GroovyMock of a static method.  When my mock method is called the test fails because the correct arguments were not used, even though I accept all arguments to the mock.  Why is this please?

```
// FileDownloadingService.groovy
class FileDownloadingService {

    // I am going to mock this static method
    static void download(URL urlLocation, String localDir, String localName) {
    }
}


// ServiceUnderTestService.groovy
class ServiceUnderTestService {
    def downloadData(URL url) {
        FileDownloadingService.download(url, "temp", "ReferenceData.gz")

    }
}


// within ServiceUnderTestServiceSpec
void "file is downloaded"() {
    given: "A url for the file to download"
    def urlLocation = "http://example.com/ReferenceData.gz"
    def url = new URL(urlLocation)
    def fileDownloadMock = GroovyMock(FileDownloadingService, global: true)

    when: "we call downloadData"
    service.downloadData(url)

    then: "we actually try to download it"
    1 * fileDownloadMock.download(_, _, _)
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
|  Too few invocations for:
1 * fileDownloadMock.download(_, _, _)   (0 invocations)
Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):
1 * fileDownloadMock.download(http://example.com/ReferenceData.gz, 'temp', 'ReferenceData.gz')
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:78)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:76)
```

Why does the mock not pass, as I'm specifying all parameters are valid, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a static method, the interaction needs to be specified as follows:

```
1 * FileDownloadingService.download(*_) // or: (_, _, _)
```